# binary string to decimal number in c

Tags: c

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code!
It returns 208 as a decimal 
where it should be 0

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;

int CONVERTION_BinStrToDecimal(char* binstr) //transform a inary string to a decimal number
{
    int cpts = 0;
    unsigned char dec = 0;
    uchar x = 0;
    for (cpts = 0; cpts <= 7; cpts++) {
        x = 7 - cpts;
        dec += (binstr[cpts]*pow(2,x));
    }
    return dec;
}

int main()
{
    uchar decimal = 0;
    char bin[8] = "00000000"; //example
    decimal = CONVERTION_BinStrToDecimal(bin);
    printf("%d", decimal);
}
```

Comment: Rather than `dec += next_digit_value << x` in the loop, may I suggest `dec = (dec << 1) + next_digit_value` ?  It saves having to construct `x` -- noting that in order to construct `x` you need to know how many digits you are processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`binstr[cpts]` yields the ascii code of `0` or `1` (which is 0x30 or 0x31).

You need to use `binstr[cpts] == '1'` to convert a ascii '1' to the number 1 and everything else to `0` (assuming that no other characters may occur). Another option would be `binstr[cpts] - '0'`.

Btw, using the `pow()` function is disregarded for such cases, better substitute `pow(2,x)` by `(1<<x)`.

```
for (cpts = 0; cpts <= 7; cpts++) {
    x = 7 - cpts;
    dec += ((binstr[cpts] == '1')*(1 << x));
}
```

There are many possibilities to make it look nicer, of course, the most obvious being `(binstr[cpts] == '1') << x`.

Furthermore, mind that your code expects exactly 8 binary digits to calculate the correct result.

Comment: I am simulating an rs232/UART communication by receiving a random number between 0 and 1 and I am stuck in converting 8 received 0s and 1s to ascii before storing them in a circular buffer, 
if i add `printf("dec %d = %d\n", cpts, dec);`after `dec += (binstr[cpts]*pow(2,x));` I get the first 4 as 0s and then it jumps to 128

Comment: @aouainia You mean, you need to convert it to an integer, correct? Yes, that's what I addressed in the answer. Does it work?

Comment: Btw. the function name "BinStrToDecimal" is a bit of a misnomer, because what you really convert is the type: _string representing a number in binary system_ to an _integer_ (which is not really in a number system, also not decimal). I now added the fixed code for your comfort

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you zero-terminate your string you can use [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function with base 2, e.g.:

```
char bin[9] = "00000000";
decimal = strtol(bin, NULL, 2);
```

Comment: yes i tried it but it does only work if your bin is const char* whereas I would need this function to use it in a state machine that fills bin with 8 0s or 1s, in which case the strtol won't work, i tried it as a first thought xD

Comment: @aouainia For `strtol` you just need to zero-terminate your string. E.g. `char bin[9] = "00000000";`